# Securimage can't validate form

Tags: php, forms

I tried using Securimage but it the form always post to another page even if I enter wrong captcha. How to validate the captcha first then only submit the form to the posted page? The form keeps redirecting me to the posted page eventhoguht the capcha is not validated. Please advice.

```
<?php session_start(); 

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action = "login.php" method = "post">

  <p>
    <label for="ct_name">Name*:</label>
    <?php echo @$_SESSION['ctform']['name_error'] ?>
    <input type="text" name="ct_name" size="35" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$_SESSION['ctform']['ct_name']) ?>" />
  </p>


  <p>
    <?php
      // show captcha HTML using Securimage::getCaptchaHtml()
    include_once 'genius_gadget/../securimage/securimage.php';
      $options = array();
      $options['input_name'] = 'ct_captcha'; // change name of input element for form post

      echo Securimage::getCaptchaHtml($options);
    ?>
  </p>

  <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
</form>


<?php

    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){


        if ($_POST['ct_name'] <> "") {

        require_once 'genius_gadget/../securimage/securimage.php';      
        $securimage = new Securimage();

              if ($securimage->check($captcha) == false) {
                echo 'Incorrect security code entered';
              }
            }

        else{

            echo "Success";

        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Remove the `@` from your code. We cannot help you if you hide errors that may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Tidied up the code... Tested on PHP 5.3.29

```
<?php // login.php
session_start();

//  1) Move the check logic before the login page display
//  2) Moved the options to the start - easy to see the input_name
//  3) fixed 'undefined variable $captcha message as incorrect input name used.
//  4) Always need the 'securimage.pph' script so move it to top of the file
//  5) Change the include path as it ignores the first directory
//  6) Always need a 'Secureimage' object so create it at the start.
//  7) Added HTML closing tags
//  8) Ensure that the input name value comes from $_POST not the $_SESSION.
//  9) Changed the 'ct_name' if test to cause an error if not entered.
// 10) Ensure that if captcha is valid the the 'success' path is executed

include_once '/securimage/securimage.php';

$options = array();
$options['input_name'] = 'ct_captcha'; // change name of input element for form post

$securimage = new Securimage($options);


    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){


        if ($_POST['ct_name'] <> "") {

            if ($securimage->check($_POST['ct_captcha']) == false) {
                echo 'Incorrect security code entered';
             }
            else{
                echo "Success";
                exit;
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'Name not entered';
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action = "login.php" method = "post">

  <p>
    <label for="ct_name">Name*:</label>
    <?php echo @$_SESSION['ctform']['name_error'] ?>
    <input type="text" name="ct_name" size="35" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$_POST['ct_name']) ?>" />
  </p>


  <p>
    <?php
      // show captcha HTML using Securimage::getCaptchaHtml()
      echo Securimage::getCaptchaHtml($options);
    ?>
  </p>

  <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Other than tidying up the code, what exactly did you do?